# Encrypting a web.config file and supplying the path to the file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis

I am encrypying my .NET config file using this command and it works just fine:

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication"
```

For this to work though I have to have a virtual directory called SampleApplication pointing to the folder my web.config file is under.

Is there a way to just specify the path to the file and not have to have a virtual dir?

I tried with

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -location "c:\FoldercontainingWebConfigFile"
```

but i get the error: " path attribute must be a relative virtual path". And cannot contain any of ":" "\" etc...

I am looking here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it with!

-pef "sectionName" "full path to directory containing web.config file"

Comment: full path can also be . if you execute the code form the application folder where the web.config resides

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this tool](http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2009/07/16/encrypt-your-web-config-please/) - it loads all your IIS sites and vdirs, and lets you pick the file (and section) you want to encrypt/decrypt.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I actually need to achieve this through c# code where you pass in the path to the file and the section you want to encrypt  and then the aspnet_regiis util does the work. Do yo know if this is possible?